# How i can open pdf into iphone for selected pdf viewer?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

if you get pdf file in mailbox, long tap pdf file , then you will get popup box with list of pdf reader app's you have installed. so how can add our app on there to open pdf file?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Introduction/Introduction.html ?

Answer (score 0):

With the [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)onOpenWith:(UIButton *)theButton path:(NSString *)path
{   
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    if (URL) {
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

        self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
        [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero
                                              inView:theButton
                                            animated:YES];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view.frame;
}
```